# How do you append a specific row from one data frame to another Data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one data frame. I am sorting out particular values from it and want to input that row of data. In this case the time, which is the index, and the action of which is happening. I have the row number that I want to input however, when I try doing this,

```
a = a.append(data.values[i])
```

or

```
a = a.append(data.iloc[i])
```

I receive the error append() missing one required positional argument: 'other'

This may be a very simple problem. However, I am knew to this library and data structure, and looking for some insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
a = pd.concat([a, data.iloc[i].to_frame().T], axis=0)
```

### Edit

Made some changes to the solution based on your replies. Is this what you're looking for?

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# NOTE: If you get an ImportError message, execute
#       ``pip install dateutil`` and then try importing it once more.
#       We're using dateutil only to create some sample data.
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


# == Generating some Sample Data ====================================
start_date = pd.Timestamp("2022-10-31 07:07:00-07:00")
start_value = 106.689470
data = []

for minute in range(1000):
    new_date = start_date + relativedelta(minutes=minute)
    start_value += np.random.random()/5
    data.append([new_date, start_value])


a = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date', 'value'])
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'value'])
print(data)
# Prints:
#                          date       value
# 0   2022-10-31 07:07:00-07:00  106.780163
# 1   2022-10-31 07:08:00-07:00  106.848128
# 2   2022-10-31 07:09:00-07:00  106.853968
# 3   2022-10-31 07:10:00-07:00  107.031727
# 4   2022-10-31 07:11:00-07:00  107.162009
# ..                        ...         ...
# 995 2022-10-31 23:42:00-07:00  206.323596
# 996 2022-10-31 23:43:00-07:00  206.369448
# 997 2022-10-31 23:44:00-07:00  206.530771
# 998 2022-10-31 23:45:00-07:00  206.563843
# 999 2022-10-31 23:46:00-07:00  206.578507

# [1000 rows x 2 columns]


# == Iterating through ``data`` =========================================
last_value = None
counter = 0
rows = []

for index, row in data.sort_values('value', ascending=True).iterrows():
    if last_value is None:
        last_value = row['value']
    elif last_value < row['value']:
        counter += 1
    if counter == 7:
        # Appending rows from every 7th increment of column value
        rows.append(row)
        counter = 0
    last_value = row['value']

print(pd.concat([a, pd.DataFrame(rows)], axis=0))
# Prints:
#                          date       value
# 7   2022-10-31 07:14:00-07:00  107.414896
# 14  2022-10-31 07:21:00-07:00  108.334858
# 21  2022-10-31 07:28:00-07:00  109.272097
# 28  2022-10-31 07:35:00-07:00  109.925929
# 35  2022-10-31 07:42:00-07:00  110.790899
# ..                        ...         ...
# 966 2022-10-31 23:13:00-07:00  203.446998
# 973 2022-10-31 23:20:00-07:00  204.212482
# 980 2022-10-31 23:27:00-07:00  204.986892
# 987 2022-10-31 23:34:00-07:00  205.609712
# 994 2022-10-31 23:41:00-07:00  206.244629

# [142 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Howdy, When I do this, I get the error. '>' not supported between instances of 'property' and 'int'. Do you know what this is from?

Comment: I edited this comment, it wouldn't let me edit the other one.Howdy, When I do this, I get the error. '>' not supported between instances of 'property' and 'int.' Do you know what this is from? Edited, if I remove the a in the Concat function, the error is gone, Do I need the a in the Concat function? however, this is in a for loop and it is resetting every time it loops is there a way to prevent this.

Comment: @BEn can you give some sample data that is resulting in the error messages?

Comment: @BEn I see... Are you trying to append ALL lines from `data` into `a`?

Comment: @BEn If so, you could simply use `a = pd.concat([data, a], axis=0)`

Comment: 2022-10-31 07:07:00-07:00  106.689470
2022-10-31 07:08:00-07:00  106.825397
2022-10-31 07:09:00-07:00  106.961534
2022-10-31 07:10:00-07:00  107.097884
2022-10-31 07:11:00-07:00  107.234451                                                                             This is some sample data. There are about 1,000 lines of this. I have a for loop that sorts through this to find every 7 th increment of the second collum. I am trying to add the whole role of the selected data to a new data frame. The data above is stored in a data frame. I am not trying to append all lines, just some, about 20

Comment: That is formatted weirdly, but it is the date and time followed by a float. The colloms are the date and time as the first collum, and the other collum is the float.

Comment: @BEn I've edited the original answer. Does the new implementation works for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "foo": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "spam": [5, 6, 7, 8]
})
print(f"{df1}\n")

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "foo": [11, 12, 13, 14],
    "spam": [20, 22, 24, 26]
})
print(f"{df2}\n")

df1.loc[df2.index[0]] = df2.iloc[0]
print(df1)

   foo  spam
0    1     5
1    2     6
2    3     7
3    4     8

   foo  spam
0   11    20
1   12    22
2   13    24
3   14    26

   foo  spam
0   11    20
1    2     6
2    3     7
3    4     8
```